# Make a checkbox / radio label bold on check with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to make the parent `label` element bold on a radio / checkbox check. It's working for checkboxes, but the radio's label stays bold.

### HTML:

```
<h4>Radios:</h4>
<div class="checkgroup">
    <label for="green"><input type="radio" name="test" id="green">Green</label>
    <label for="blue"><input type="radio" name="test" id="blue">Blue</label>
    <label for="red"><input type="radio" name="test" id="red">Red</label>
</div>
<hr />
<h4>Checkboxes:</h4>
<div class="checkgroup">
    <label for="green-check"><input type="checkbox" id="green-check">Green</label>
    <label for="blue-check"><input type="checkbox" id="blue-check">Blue</label>
    <label for="red-check"><input type="checkbox" id="red-check">Red</label>
</div>
```

### JavaScript:

```
function makeLabelBold() {
    const radios = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio']");
    const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");

    radios.forEach((radio) => {
        radio.addEventListener("click", function () {
            this.checked
                ? (this.parentElement.style.fontWeight = "700")
                : (this.parentElement.style.fontWeight = "400");
        });
    });

    checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
        checkbox.addEventListener("click", function () {
            this.checked
                ? (this.parentElement.style.fontWeight = "700")
                : (this.parentElement.style.fontWeight = "400");
        });
    });
}

makeLabelBold();
```

I tried using a `change` event instead of a click, but that didn't work. Any ideas? Here's a Pen to try out.

### Codepen:

[Codepen for testing](https://codepen.io/Sackadelic/pen/XWMjdLO)

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use JavaScript and not plain old CSS?

Comment: I'm locked in with my HTML as it's a plugin on Woocommerce. And, since I can't select a parent selector, I have to use JS. If I'm missing something, let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this without JavaScript. You can use `:checked` CSS selector. Something like this:

```css
input:checked + span {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<h4>Radios:</h4>
<div class="checkgroup">
    <label for="green"><input type="radio" name="test" id="green"><span>Green</span></label>
    <label for="blue"><input type="radio" name="test" id="blue"><span>Blue</span></label>
    <label for="red"><input type="radio" name="test" id="red"><span>Red</span></label>
</div>
<hr />
<h4>Checkboxes:</h4>
<div class="checkgroup">
    <label for="green-check"><input type="checkbox" id="green-check"><span>Green</span></label>
    <label for="blue-check"><input type="checkbox" id="blue-check"><span>Blue</span></label>
    <label for="red-check"><input type="checkbox" id="red-check"><span>Red</span></label>
</div>
```

### If you would like to use JavaScript anyway:

Radio lists doesn't fire event for each of its radio box but only for the one which has been really changed (which you have clicked / as long as we are not changing its value programmaticaly). What I did:

- replaced `this` with `e.target` to get `radio` which you have clicked.
- get it's `name` attribute with `getAttribute("name")`
- find all radios with same `name` attribute`
- remove style from all radios with this attribute
- apply style on currently selected `radio`

```js
function makeLabelBold() {
    const radios = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio']");
    const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");

    radios.forEach((radio) => {
        radio.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            const inputsName = e.target.getAttribute("name");
            const sameNameRadios = document.querySelectorAll("[name='"+inputsName+"']");
            sameNameRadios.forEach(radio=>{
               radio.parentElement.style.fontWeight = "400";
            });
            e.target.parentElement.style.fontWeight = "700";
            
        });
    });

    checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
        checkbox.addEventListener("click", function () {
            this.checked
                ? (this.parentElement.style.fontWeight = "700")
                : (this.parentElement.style.fontWeight = "400");
        });
    });
}

makeLabelBold();
```

```html
<h4>Radios:</h4>
<div class="checkgroup">
    <label for="green"><input type="radio" name="test" id="green">Green</label>
    <label for="blue"><input type="radio" name="test" id="blue">Blue</label>
    <label for="red"><input type="radio" name="test" id="red">Red</label>
</div>
<hr />
<h4>Checkboxes:</h4>
<div class="checkgroup">
    <label for="green-check"><input type="checkbox" id="green-check">Green</label>
    <label for="blue-check"><input type="checkbox" id="blue-check">Blue</label>
    <label for="red-check"><input type="checkbox" id="red-check">Red</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm locked in on my HTML  - it's a plugin and I was hoping to use simple CSS but my research dictates I can't select the input's parent, which is the Label.

Comment: Well it is named **Cascade** Style Sheets so you can't select parent, but you can select next element with `+`. So you are not able to implement another `span` around the _string_ as I did? Do you still need JS version?

Comment: No, I can't wrap the label text in a `span`. I wish. The JS version is working well, it's just not working on the Radios. Once clicked, the radio stays bolded - where the checkbox does not.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I appreciate the help and explaination.

Comment: Well it's not the best solution but I hope it helps you somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Without changing the HTML:

```js
(function()
  {
  const 
    radios     = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]')
  , checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')
  ;
  radios.forEach(radio => 
    {
    radio.onclick = () => 
      radios.forEach( r =>
        r.closest('label').style.fontWeight = r.checked ? '700' : '400' )
    });
  checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => 
    {
    checkbox.onclick = () => 
      checkbox.closest('label').style.fontWeight = checkbox.checked ? '700' : '400'
    });
  }
)()
```

```html
<h4>Radios:</h4>
<div class="checkgroup">
    <label for="green"><input type="radio" name="test" id="green">Green</label>
    <label for="blue"><input type="radio" name="test" id="blue">Blue</label>
    <label for="red"><input type="radio" name="test" id="red">Red</label>
</div>
<hr />
<h4>Checkboxes:</h4>
<div class="checkgroup">
    <label for="green-check"> <input type="checkbox" id="green-check">Green</label>
    <label for="blue-check">  <input type="checkbox" id="blue-check" >Blue </label>
    <label for="red-check">   <input type="checkbox" id="red-check"  >Red  </label>
</div>
```

you can olso do:

```js
(function()
  {
  const radios_checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"]');
  radios_checkboxes.forEach(rc => 
    {
    rc.onclick =()=> 
      radios_checkboxes.forEach(elm => 
        elm.closest('label').style.fontWeight = elm.checked ? '700' : '400' )
    });
  }
)();
```

Comment: Very efficient - this is another thing I was looking for. Thanks!